# Multiple File Upload PHP from Div tag

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Here Is the code :

```
<div action="form_upload.html" class="drop zone" name="file upload"></div>
```

I got the code from the bootstrap template. there is no Input file tag.
how can I upload file from that div to mysql using PHP.
I tried upload using common way,
but I can't get the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the whole scenario but in my understanding, you want a div behaving like a file input tag. So you can do this like this

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" style="display:none"/> <!--Set display none -->
<div id="OpenImgUpload">File Upload</div>
```

And on the div's click event write the jQuery code like :

```
$('#OpenImgUpload').click(function(){ $('#fileupload').trigger('click'); });
```

Rest you can apply further jquery code for [submitting](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp) the form values